# Why calculation variable in JavaScript Promises does not recognise at outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var appCounts = 0;
applicationsService.getApplicationCountByJob(job.id).then((appcount) => {
    appCounts = appCounts + appcount;
});
company.applications = appCounts;
```

appCount has lost value in `company.applications = appCounts;`

Please let me know how to solve that issue.

Comment: duplicate of how to return a result from an async function, but I can't find that question

Answer (score 0):

your function getApplicationCountByJob is probably asynchronous, meaning

```
company.applications = appCounts;
```

gets executed before

```
appCounts = appCounts + appcount;
```

move inside another then to get it work:

```
var appCounts = 0;
applicationsService.getApplicationCountByJob(job.id)
.then((appcount) => {
    appCounts = appCounts + appcount;
})
.then(() => {
  company.applications = appCounts;
});
```